# Why is supersymmetry limited by $\frac{N}{4}$?

Tags: representation-theory, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions

So in many people notes [Bertolini's](https://people.sissa.it/%7Ebertmat/susycourse.pdf) for example on page 9 it is stated that the limit of $N$ for SUSY is bound by $\frac{N}{4}$ in 4D. I understand that elementary particles can't have spin higher than 2 so we cant go past $N=8$ but could somebody please explain where this $\frac{N}{4}$ comes from I know that it is something to do with the spin but I'm not 100% sure the full explanation.

Comment: "$N$ is bound by $\frac{N}{4}$" doesn't really make a lot of sense. Are these supposed to be two different $N$s?

Comment: @ACuriousMind sorry i have trouble explaining things sometimes. $N$ can not be arbitrarily large as $\frac{N}{4}$ must be less than the spin of the graviton.

Comment: Please edit your question to make this more clear. Also, the notes you link seem to discuss this more or less explicitly in chapter 3.